# How to use FOR to find string in file, strip it of spaces, set variable to it for token?

Tags: batch-file

```
@ECHO off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "VAR=da da da YES123123"
echo %VAR% > testing.txt

FOR /F %%a in ('findstr "YES" .\testing.txt') do (
                                                 set BLAH=%%a
                                                 set "BLAH2=%BLAH: =%"
                                                 set "FINAL=%BLAH2:~15%"
                                                 echo %FINAL%
                                                 )

endlocal
```

Whether WITH or WITHOUT "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" the batch file simply does not work.

But that's all I have so far. However I also want to strip the preceding characters from the FINDSTR string, but set a variable to the FINDSTR string AND IT'S SUCCEEDING 123123 characters. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. It only outputs "ECHO is off."

I have used FOR correctly in other ways, but I can't figure it out this time. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You need to invoke delayedexpansion [hundreds of SO articles about that - use the search feature] in order to display or use the run-time value of any string variable that's changed within a parenthesised series of instructions (aka "code block").

Comment: Search for [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) on this site; alternatively, do the sub-string extraction after the loop as your file contains only a single line anyway...

Comment: yeah I've tried it with setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion already. It's the same result, even if I change out the % to the ! (except for the cookie)

Comment: What do you want to get back? `YES123123`? Is it always the last "word"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get the last word, use a plain `for` to split your string by default delimiters (space, tab, comma, =). No need to know, how many tokens there are. The following works, even if there are more lines with `YES`:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "YES" .\testing.txt') do (
  for %%b in (%%a) do set final=%%b
  echo !final!
)
```

**EDIT** to find `YES` until end of line:

There is a token `*` for "all the rest", so you could do:

```
for /f "tokens=3,* delims= " %%a in ('findstr "YES" .\testing.txt') do echo %%b
```

but I recommend another method (replacing `*YES` with just `YES`). `set` can do limited wildcard replacement (`*string` works, but `string*` does not). Advantage: you don't need to know, which token `YES...` is:

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('findstr "YES" testing.txt') do (
  set line=%%a
  echo !line:* YES=YES!
)
```

Comment: thank you SO much man! I am having a really hard times with this token stuff! That works!

Answer (score 1):

Understand first meaning
**`Tokens`** mean take only the column  1 or 2 or ...... of stdout

**`skip`** mean skip line 1,2........... from the list of text of stdout

**`delims`** mean the way this columns seperated between each other with what (space or dot or slash ..........)

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i figured it out. Had to use the "token=1,2,3,4, delim= " thing, which I hate using and it's confusing but have used it before for other purposes. I was just really confused on how to echo or set the variable to the token at the end of the command. Here is the corrected code.

```
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "YES" .\testing.txt') do echo %%d
```

Comment: same can be done with `FOR /F "tokens=4 delims= " %%a in ('findstr "YES" .\testing.txt') do echo %%a` - same logic, but shorter to write.

Comment: thanks a lot. This crap is hard and I've been spending hours trying to get it to work lol. I search over ever post on here just about heh.

Comment: Thanks again btw, how would one go about changing the YES123123 (that's token 4 or %%d) to YES 123 123 and STILL echo "YES 123 123". Of course the spaces are the delims, and unfortunately, the txt file is going to be a wild card at the end, I can always get the 4th token, but if the wildcard string has spaces, I don't know how to use FOR to adjust for that! I am not going to know how long the 4th token is or how many spaces it has... so it's difficult!

Comment: I agree. You always search for `YES<until end of line>`?

Comment: I will know that "YES" will be part of the string always, but I'm not sure how to append a wild card amount of tokens AFTER yes to the variable %%a. I just don't know what will be there after yes. it could be "YES123123" or it could be "YES 59 f 39 f3 f329 f###" for all i know.